# how to get same invoice number data to datagridview column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, datagridview

I'm going to design an invoice system. well, I have 2 table call invoice and sub-invoice.

[image: tables]

I want to select all the checked columns and show it in `DataGridView`

[image: datagridview]

[image: invoice table with data]
[image: sub invoice table with data]

but I need to put sub-invoice.subject-name in that `DataGridView` subject column like *maths, English, ict*. please help me.

Comment: You need to use a join statement to combine the two tables.  See msdn samles : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b.  You can put the results into a datatable and then make the table the datasource for the DGV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your explanation you need to query both of these tables from SQL Server Database and then insert data into `DataGridView` class.

Here is how you can query to get data from both tables

```
SELECT i.InvoiceNo, i.StudentId, i.StudentName, 
       i.Grade, i.TotalAmount, si.SubjectName
FROM Invoice i
JOIN SubInvoice si ON i.InvoiceNo = si.InvoiceNo;
```

Here is the link of how to use `DataGridView` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: ok. thank you David_Zizu. but in this case, I have more than one recode of sub-invoice base on the i.InvoiceNo, I need to select one invoice number as an example 'INV-12' then I get more than one record. I need to show all these records in datagridview singe row, therefore somehow I need to show all sub-invoice SubjectName to the datagridview subject column like ='maths,ict' like that. sorry for my bad english

Comment: In this case, what you can do is to query db at first using the query above and after that use dictionary where the key = `string InvoiceNumber` and value = new class which consists of all the following properties `string InvoiceNumber, int StudentId, string  StudentName, int Grade, double TotalAmount, List<string> Subjects`. I am not sure how you query your db but if for example, you use dapper as your orm you could basically supply a lambda function and correctly map all the results from your query to a dictionary.